Martial Arts movie with 2 protagonist cops from the late 80's or early 90's
Been looking a while. A late 80's or early 90's movie I believe where a Serial killer Martial Arts expert seeks out the top 10 Martial Arts experts to fight to the death to find a worthy opponent. There are 2 Martial Arts cops too on his trail and one fights him at the end. One cop is white I believe and one is Black. I thought one was Billy Blanks but I looked at his filmography and found nothing.

Sounds suspiciously like Enter the Dragon (1973, Bruce Lee), but some of the details are not the same

Richard was right. It was Bloodmoon. Thanks you guys!!! I can't believe I forgot about his steel fingers. Wow the internet is so useful.
